# Total Users Per Day

Tags: mysql

### **Problem**

I want to show all users for a specific range lets say `from 2020-01-01` to `from 2020-01-05`.

I have a table `user` where all users are saved. Imagine following table:

```
user

    id | createdAt
     1   2020-01-01
     2   2020-01-02
     3   2020-01-03
     4   2020-01-03
     5   2020-01-05
```

The outcome should be (relating to the above user table):

```
        date | count

  2020-01-01    1
  2020-01-02    2
  2020-01-03    4
  2020-01-04    4
  2020-01-05    5
```

### **What I have so far**

I have a query that returns the example above as needed:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user u WHERE DATE(u.createdAt) <= DATE(dates.gen_date) AND u.role = 'USER' GROUP BY dates.gen_date ),0) AS y, dates.gen_date AS x FROM user u, (select * from
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where gen_date between DATE(?) and DATE(?)) AS dates GROUP BY x;
```

But the execution of this statement is really slow by huge number of users and a large time range.

I thought also of a materialized view but this would be only the last way out.

Database used: **MySql 5.7**

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Please show Creating of table. Are you using the INDEXES for optimise data access?

Comment: What is max possible dates range (in days) for which you need to generate your output?

Comment: There should be no limitation, but it will not exceed 7 years (= 2555 days)

Comment: Are you shure that problem in Request? Or the problem in GUI?

Comment: Does the specified expected result really match the given sample data?!?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE user; for analysis.

Comment: I solved it by handling it in application code as suggested by Strawberry. Any help was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT (dates.mindate + INTERVAL (t0.n+10*t1.n+100*t2.n+1000*t3.n) DAY) `date`,
       COUNT(users.id) `count`
FROM users,
     (SELECT ? mindate, ? maxdate) dates,
     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 n union select 1 union select 2) t3
WHERE users.createdAt <= (dates.mindate + INTERVAL (t0.n+10*t1.n+100*t2.n+1000*t3.n) DAY)
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING `date` <= dates.maxdate
ORDER BY `date`
```

It must be less expensive.